Why do bash single quotes interpret "\n" as newlines?
According to documentation, single quotes in bash preserve all literal characters, however the following:
echo 'a\nb'

Outputs:
a
b

(i.e. the literal \ and n have been replaced with a newline)
Why is this the case? (what am I missing?)
Also, what other characters does this affect?
For reference I'm using GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin22)

I cannot repro this. Perhaps you have alias echo='echo -e' or some such; but this behavior is not reproducible out of the box. Tested with 3.2.57(1)-release from MacOS Sonoma and 5.2.26(1)-release from Homebrew.

Not sure what was written in bash3 documentation, probably xpg compat is set somewhere in env (firstly check it out with shopt xpg_echo). And compare shopt -u xpg_echo && echo 'a\nb' vs shopt -s xpg_echo && echo 'a\nb'

It looks like this can be reproduced, depending on the shell options. Certainly @user1934428's answer is valuable, so I think this should not be closed.

bash doesn't do it in general. The bash builtin echo does. But if you had written it as $'a\nb', bash would have done the interpretation on the string itself.
UPDATE As @yvs2014 pointed out, even this behaviour of echo can be turned configured. If you do a
shopt -s xpg_echo

the builtin echo expands the escape sequences. If you do a
shopt -u xpg_echo

it does not.

behavior of bash builtin echo depends on shell options at runtime and configure options at build time

@yvs2014 : Which shell option would cause that the echo builtin would not interpret \n ?

as it's written above it depends on xpg_echo option

@yvs2014 : Ah, thanks. I will update my answer accordingly.
